# Are questions asking for opinion regarding all edge cases on topic?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I have been away from code review for some time and not sure on the scope agreed upon in the community.

So is [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/119524/add-weekdays-to-date) on topic or off topic? Basically the below is on topic or not?

> Will the below code work for adding Weekdays in all possible scenarios?

I understand that reviewer can ignore what is specifically asked in the question. But still is it on topic?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it okay to give a review without actually answering some of the OP's requests?](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5773/is-it-okay-to-give-a-review-without-actually-answering-some-of-the-ops-requests)

Comment: @Phrancis I'm not sure if this is a dupe of that. That post is about answers, and whether or not it's okay to not address the OP's questions. This question is about questions (a specific one) and whether or not it's on topic.

Answer (score 7):

The rules haven't changed.  The standard is, does the code work correctly, to the best of the author's knowledge?

If the question explicitly identifies a bug and asks for a fix, then it would be clearly off-topic.

If the question is very obviously broken (won't compile, looks wrong by inspection, or fails for simple test cases), I'll generally close it too, to prevent abuse.  That kind of closure is not necessarily unhelpful: it's a useful form of feedback in its own right, and lets us focus on more insightful issues when the bug is fixed and the question is reopened.

Otherwise, I would tend to give the poster the benefit of the doubt, and assume that the code does work to the best of the author's knowledge.

Comment: Indeed, the question almost seems like a plea to ask "Are there edge cases I'm not aware of that will bite me down the road?"